# mysql - count of two columns of a table and one column from another

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I want this queries to get into one:

```
select count(first_column) as first from table1 where user_id = $id
select count(second_column) as second from table1 where user_id = $id
select count(first_column) as third from table2 where user_id = $id
```

I have this:

```
select COUNT(table1.first_column) AS first, 
       COUNT(table1.second_column) AS second, 
       COUNT(table2.first_column) AS third 
from table2 inner join
        table2 on table1.user_id = table2.user_id 
where table1.user_id = 1;
```

but it returns wrong values for table2.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you give example data, your output and the desired ouput ?

Comment: i have follows and followed from table1 and posts from table2. I want to count users follows, followed and posts count. the datas are like this: user_id:1, follows:11, followed:null - user_id:1, follows:24, followed:null - user_id:1, follows:null, followed:54 and in posts table post_id:22, user_id:1 - post_id:26, user_id:1. when I add group by table2.post_id it returns correct of table1 but not for table2. the follows and followed are the ids of target user_id not the count here.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use subqueries:

```
select (select count(first_column) as first from table1 where user_id = $id) as first,
       (select count(second_column) as second from table1 where user_id = $id) as second,
       (sselect count(first_column) as third from table2 where user_id = $id) as third;
```

Because the first two come from the same table, you might consider:

```
select count(t1.first_column), count(t1.second_column), t2.third_column
from table1 t1 cross join
     (select count(third_column as third from table2) t2
where t1.user_id = $id;
```

This will work in MySQL.  In other databases, you would need an aggregation function for the third column.